# JMenu and JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, illegalargumentexception, jmenu, jmenuitem

So, I have the following code:

```
JMenu debug = new JMenu("Debug");
    debug.add(new Debug());
```

And then the Debug class is:

```
public class Debug extends JMenuItem {

    public final String TEST_DEBUG = "Test";

    public Debug() {
        add(TEST_DEBUG, this);
    }
}
```

After running the application I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding container's parent to itself

I know what it means, but I have no idea how I can make this right without placing the container parent to itself? How would I pass the String to the JMenu?

I am trying to pass the String (TEST_DEBUG) to the JMenu (debug), through the Debug class.

Comment: Problem is in constructor of `Debug` class. By passing `this`, you are trying to add Debug (it's JMenuItem) on itself.

Comment: I see. How would I pass the String to the JMenu? Using the Debug constructor.

Comment: What string and from where?

Comment: public final String TEST_DEBUG = "Test";

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW - Why extend `JMenuItem` at all?  Just use instances of them.

Comment: It doesn't explain anything. I'm totally confused what you are trying to achieve. At least me.

Comment: I already read the post & looked at the code snippets.  The post and code snippets explain nothing I need to know.  Post an SSCCE and explicitly answer my question.

Comment: I have redone the post. I am sorry.

Comment: Take a look at the [`Action` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html), it would greatly simplify the matter...

Comment: *"I am trying to pass the String (TEST_DEBUG) to the JMenu (debug), through the Debug class."*  Yeah.  I think everyone that cares already understands that.  Where is the SSCCE?  What is the answer to my question?!?

Comment: It does not make sense to want to "add" anything to the `JMenuItem`, it is a button...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

[`JMenuItem#add(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#add%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public Debug() {
        add(TEST_DEBUG);
    }
```

EDIT:

```
public class Debug extends JMenuItem {

    public Debug() {
        setText("");
    }
    public Debug(String text){
     add(text);
   }
   }
```

Then:

```
Debug obj = new Debug("text one");
Debug obj2 = new Debug("text two");
Debug obj3 =new Debug();
debug.add(obj);
debug.add(obj2);
debug.add(obj3);
```

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't work. My IDE asks for: JMenuItem#add(String s, Component c)

Comment: How about `setText(TEST_DEBUG);` ?

Comment: Yes that worked, but if I wanted to add more Strings, it will just have one.

Comment: This method adds the string to the button, when you add another string, it'll replace the old string.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you cant add a container to itself, thats what you're doing ..

change your code to

```
class DEBUG extends JMenuItem{ 

     public final String TEST_DEBUG = "Test";
    DEBUG(){
        JMenuItem addme = new JMenuItem(TEST_DEBUG);
    this.add(addme);    
    }
}
```

then in your main class

```
     debug.add(new Debug());
```

that should work

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
public class Debug extends JMenuItem {

    public final String TEST_DEBUG = "Test";

    public Debug() {
        add(TEST_DEBUG, this);
    }
}
```

...does not make any sense.  You are saying, "I want to add myself to myself with the constraint of `TEST_DEBUG`"....`JMenuItem` is a type of button, if you want to set it's text you should use

JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(TEST_DEBUG);

Then add this to your `JMenu`...

If you want to re-use the menu item or it's action, you should make use of the [`Actions` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)